# In SwiftUI, how do you make a DatePicker that lets the user pick Nov. 7, 2021, 1:30 AM without DST applied?

Tags: swift, date, picker, dst

In SwiftUI, how do you make a DatePicker that lets the user pick Nov. 7, 2021, 1:30 AM without DST applied? (I.e. a DatePicker that lets the user specify whether to apply DST or not to the time in question.)

I made a SwiftUI DatePicker however if you select Nov. 7, 2021, 1:30 AM it always has DST applied (you get 1636273841.499107 seconds since 1970). But if you select 2:30 AM it never has DST applied (you get 1636281041.499107).

In other words, if there are two SwiftUI DatePickers, with one set to Nov. 7, 2021, 1:30 AM, and the other set to Nov. 7, 2021, 2:30 AM, then the underlying Swift Date objects will always be **two hours apart**!

However at 2:00 AM, when DST ends in Pacific Time, our clocks must be rolled back to 1AM again. That means the hour from 1:00:00–1:59:59AM occurs twice on Nov. 7, 2021. This is a fact, it's not up for debate or question.

So how can we enable the user to specify which 1:30 AM they mean on Nov. 7, 2021? If they clocked in or out from work on that day at that time, which one do they mean? We need them to be able to specify this to avoid under- or over-paying them. People often fill out their time cards retroactively so we need them to be able to select the exact point in time they meant.

Also when setting someone's schedule, managers need to be able to specify whether we mean 1:30 AM with DST still applied, or 1:30 AM without DST applied. It matters, because what if all the nurses leave on the first time 1:30 AM occurs, but the next shift arrives on the second 1:30 AM?

Any insight would be most welcome.

For example, given the below code, when you increment the time from 1:00 to 1:01, the "offsetFrom1AM" property changes from 60 minutes to 1 minute! This is very messed up...

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

struct DateView: View {
    private static let nov_7_2021_1AM_PDT = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1636272000)
    private static let nov_7_2021_1AM_PST = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1636272000 + 60*60)
    
    @State var date: Date = nov_7_2021_1AM_PST
    
    var offsetFrom1AM: TimeInterval {
        date.timeIntervalSince(DateView.nov_7_2021_1AM_PDT)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("DatePicker", selection: $date)
                .onChange(of: date) { date in 
                    print("\(date.timeIntervalSince1970)")
                }
        }
        HStack {
            Text("\(offsetFrom1AM/60) minutes")
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(DateView())
```

Comment: The easiest approach would be to use UTC time. Another option is to create a custom picker controller if the date is a daylight savings transition

Comment: Sucks that a single edge case in the middle of the night once per year means we can't use the the default picker. Seems like an oversight on Apple's part, tbh.

Comment: You tell the difference with the TimeZone for the first 1AM it will be PDT for the second it will be PST. `Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute, .timeZone], from: datePDT, to: datePST)`is designed to give you the correct # of hours. `Date` is in UTC any time a date is created it is written and read with UTC and timezone adjusted if provided.